# Объединие результатов mysql_fetch_array

Tags: php

День добрый.
Как можно объединить или вывести данные, которые выводятся с помощью mysql_fetch_array, в один массив?
Заранее спасибо.

```
// массив с категориями
$categMas = array(1 => "рук.", 2 => "спец.", 3 => "служ.");
// текущий месяц
$chMonth = 3;
// запрос для вывода всех подразделений
$sqlEDep = "SELECT id_economist, applet FROM db_economist";
$resEDep = mysql_query($sqlEDep) or die(mysql_error());
while ($rowEDep = mysql_fetch_array($resEDep)) {
    // название подразделений
    echo '<b>' . $rowEDep["applet"] . '</b> <br/>';
    // id подразделений
    $idEUser = $rowEDep["id_economist"];
    // перебор массива с категориями
    foreach ($categMas as $categ) {
        // запрос для вывода обозначений
        $sqlCount = "SELECT days "
                . "FROM db_economist, db_staff, db_sheet "
                . "WHERE id_mon = '$chMonth' AND id_personal = id_staff AND "
                . "id_econom = id_economist AND id_economist = $idEUser "
                . "AND category = '$categ' ";
        $resCount = mysql_query($sqlCount) or die(mysql_error());
        // название категории
        echo '<i>' . $categ . ' - '. mysql_num_rows($resCount) .'</i> <br/>';
        while ($rowCount = mysql_fetch_array($resCount)) {
            echo $rowCount["days"];
        }
        echo '<br/>';
    }
    echo '<br/>';
}
```

Comment: @nik_grey, ну очевидно что создать второй массив и в цикле подставить значение из `mysql_fetch_array` к имеющимся ключам.

Comment: типа вот так?
$arr = array();
-- тут запрос к бд --
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
      $arr[] = $row["names"];
}
print_r($arr);

Comment: @nik_grey, да, плюс можно ключи ставить которые вам надо, 

    $arr['name'][] = $row['names']

Comment: это я уже пробовал.. 
дело в том, что сначала запросом выводятся id подразделений, потом идет foreach с перебором категорий('рук','спец') и только потом запрос для получения нужных мне данных. 
данный метод выводит все прошлые значения и добавляет нужные..

Comment: так может стоит присмотреться к вложенным запросам?

Comment: наверное.. только вот название подразделений, категорию и обозначения каждого выводит как надо... а вот с объединением проблемы(

Comment: ``Как можно объединить или вывести данные`` вывод и объединение это не совсем одно и то же, в выборке если есть связанные таблицы, то можно **JOIN** использовать, а вывод в пхп уже как там вам заблагорассудится, т.е. через вложенные, хотя... только лишний код в пхп добавится.

Comment: давайте объясню на примере..
$chMonth = 3 - текущий месяц; 
// массив с категориями
 $categMas = array(1 => "рук.", 2 => "спец.", 3 => "служ.");

Comment: // запрос для вывода всех подразделений
    $sqlEDep = "SELECT id_economist, applet FROM db_economist";
    $resEDep = mysql_query($sqlEDep) or die(mysql_error());
    while ($rowEDep = mysql_fetch_array($resEDep)) {
        // название подразделений
        echo '<b>' . $rowEDep["applet"] . '</b> <br/>';
        // id подразделений
        $idEUser = $rowEDep["id_economist"];

Comment: // перебор массива с категориями
        foreach ($categMas as $categ) {
            // запрос для вывода обозначений
            $sqlCount = "SELECT days "
                    . "FROM db_economist, db_staff, db_sheet "
                    . "WHERE id_mon = '$chMonth' AND id_personal = id_staff AND "
                    . "id_econom = id_economist AND id_economist = $idEUser "
                    . "AND category = '$categ' ";
            $resCount = mysql_query($sqlCount) or die(mysql_error());

Comment: // название категории
            echo '<i>' . $categ . ' - '. mysql_num_rows($resCount) .'</i> <br/>';
            while ($rowCount = mysql_fetch_array($resCount)) {
                echo $rowCount["days"];
            }
            echo '<br/>';
        }
        echo '<br/>';
    }
}

Comment: ну в общем как-то так...
Отформатировал для удобства чтения

Comment: Лучше бы вы добавили этот код в текст ответа и отформатировали, а то не читаемо ИМХО

Answer (score 1):

Объясните, что вам конкретно нужно)

судя по комментариям все значения $rowCount["days"]?

тогда всё правильно говорит Сшэш - после (или вместо) echo $rowCount["days"]; ставите

```
$array[]=$rowCount["days"];
```

а после всего перебора делате так

```
<pre>
<?php print_r($array);?>
</pre>
```

Или сформулируйте вопрос подругому